# How to get the Id of one of two AutoCompleteTextViews

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm having some trouble with my onItemClick.

I'm trying to get the Id of one of my 2 AutoCompleteTextViews and I can't seem to get the right Id because when I use view.detId() the Id I get back is:

> (android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{2191ca09 V.ED....
>   ........ 0,0-984,192 #1020014 android:id/text1})

the value it should match is:
(at least if you Click on one of the two AutoCompleteTextViews)

> android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView{132917d3
>   VFED..CL .F....ID 48,282-1032,418 #7f0b0060
>   app:id/AutoCompleteTextViewQuestionAnswer}

What do I have to Change in my code to get the same Id from my .getId() as my Worker AutoComplete?

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    this.SearchName = ((AppCompatTextView) view).getText().toString();
    try {
        //The problem is being caused by this view.getId()
        if (view.getId() == this.questionWorker.getId()) {
            this.SearchPerson(this.SearchName, this.questionData);
        } else {
            this.SearchBoss(this.SearchName, this.questionData);
        }
    } catch (LDAPException ldapException) {
        Toast.makeText(this, ldapException.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }

}
```

The xml Layout looks like this:

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/AutoCompleteTextViewNameWorker"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:hint="Worker" />

<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/AutoCompleteTextViewNameBoss"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:hint="Boss" />
```

Comment: give xml layout pls with this views

Comment: what is your problem actually?

Comment: I added the xml views and clarified what my actual question is.

Comment: what is `questionWorker` ?? because i think `view.getId()` should be equal to `R.id.AutoCompleteTextViewNameBoss` or `R.id.AutoCompleteTextViewNameWorker` or any other view that has same onItemClick listener